# null pointer exepction when accessing a fragment in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am trying to access my fragment so I can call a method in it. Please any suggestions?

This is what I do in onCreate in my mainActivity:

```
mCurrent_forecast_fragment = (Current_forecast_fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.current_fragment);
```

and this is my fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/current_fragment"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iconImageView"
    android:src="@mipmap/clear_night"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:contentDescription="@string/weatherIconDesc"
    android:layout_above="@+id/locationLabel"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="requesting current location..."
    android:id="@+id/locationLabel"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeLabel"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="--"
    android:id="@+id/temperatureLabel"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="125sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/degreeImageView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/temperatureLabel"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/temperatureLabel"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/temperatureLabel"
    android:src="@mipmap/degree"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="..."
    android:id="@+id/timeLabel"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_above="@+id/degreeImageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#80ffffff"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/temperatureLabel"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HUMIDITY"
            android:id="@+id/humidityLabel"
            android:textColor="#80ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="--"
            android:id="@+id/humidityValue"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="WIND SPEED"
            android:id="@+id/windSpeedLabel"
            android:textColor="#80ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="--"
                android:id="@+id/windSpeedValue"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="KM/h"
                android:id="@+id/kmh"
                android:textColor="#80ffffff"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RAIN?"
            android:id="@+id/precipLabel"
            android:textColor="#80ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="--"
            android:id="@+id/precipValue"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Getting current weather..."
    android:id="@+id/summaryLabel"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom= "10dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/refreshImageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/refresh"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/progressBar"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my main activity layput:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          tools:context=".MainActivity">

<koemdzhiev.com.stormy.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

this is my fragment class:

```
public class Current_forecast_fragment extends Fragment {
private MainActivity mActivity;
@InjectView(R.id.timeLabel)
TextView mTimeLabel;
@InjectView(R.id.temperatureLabel)
TextView mTemperatureLabel;
@InjectView(R.id.humidityValue)
TextView mHumidityValue;
@InjectView(R.id.precipValue)
TextView mPrecipValue;
@InjectView(R.id.summaryLabel)
TextView mSummaryLabel;
@InjectView(R.id.locationLabel)
TextView mLocationLabel;
@InjectView(R.id.windSpeedValue)
TextView mWindSpeedValue;
@InjectView(R.id.iconImageView)
ImageView mIconImageView;
@InjectView(R.id.refreshImageView)
ImageView mRefreshImaveView;
@InjectView(R.id.progressBar)
ProgressBar mProgressBar;
@InjectView(R.id.degreeImageView)
ImageView mDegreeImageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mActivity = ((MainActivity) getActivity());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.current_forefast_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, v);


    return v;
}


public void toggleRefresh() {
    if (mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRefreshImaveView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mRefreshImaveView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // updates the dysplay with the data in the CUrrentWeather locaal object

}

public void updateDisplay() {
    Current current = mActivity.mForecast.getCurrent();
    //setting the current weather details to the ui
    mTemperatureLabel.setText(current.getTemperature() + "");
    mTimeLabel.setText("At " + current.getFormattedTime() + " it will be");
    mHumidityValue.setText(current.getHumidity() + "%");
    mPrecipValue.setText(current.getPrecipChange() + "%");
    mSummaryLabel.setText(current.getSummery());
    mWindSpeedValue.setText(current.getWindSpeed() + "");
    mLocationLabel.setText(current.getTimeZone());
    mActivity.getLocationName();
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mActivity, current.getIconId());
    mIconImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

}

}
```

this is where it crashes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[]={"Current","Hourly","Daily"};
int Numboftabs =3;
Current_forecast_fragment mCurrent_forecast_fragment;

public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String LOCATION_KEY = "location_key";
public Forecast mForecast;
public static final String DAILY_FORECAST = "DAILY_FORECAST";
public static final String HOURLY_FORECAST = "HOURLY_FORECAST";
//default coordinates - Gotse Delchev, UK Lati:57.156866 ; Long:
private double latitude = 41.5667;
private double longitude = 23.7333;
private LocationManager locationManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //-----------MY CODE STARTS HERE-----------------

    mCurrent_forecast_fragment = (Current_forecast_fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.current_fragment);
    Log.d("MainActivity",mCurrent_forecast_fragment.getTag() + "Georgi");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

current_fragment is id of your fragment RelativeLayout not id of your fragment so

```
mCurrent_forecast_fragment = (Current_forecast_fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.current_fragment);
```

will return null. If you want to find fragment by id place it in your activity layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/current_fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: For some reason this does not work. It again causes NullPointerException :/

Comment: Yes. This is what I am getting: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String koemdzhiev.com.stormy.Current_forecast_fragment.getTag()' on a null object reference
                                                       at koemdzhiev.com.stormy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:66)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)

Comment: It means your Current_forecast_fragment is null, can you post your activity code and xml layout?

Comment: ResolutionN i just realized that I have puted the wrong conde as my main activity here :/ will change it

Comment: Done. So Apparently. I was trying to get the fragment from my main activity, which is wrong and it make sense to get null. Do you know how I can access the fragment in my main activity so I so I cal call its methods ?

Comment: I don't see you put Current_forecast_fragment in your activity layout so you can't find it and I see you using ViewPager. Did you implement FragmentPagerAdapter?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your current xml code does not have a fragment in it.
You need to add a fragment in RelativeLayout.
You can see the full tutorial on Android Developer's site: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt to improve on ResolutioN post. The issue is likely to be the xml content and this should be easy to solve.
Sample layout:

```
<fragment
   android:name="Current_forecast_fragment"
   android:id="@+id/current_fragment"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>
```

Note: You need to insert `android:name` so that you can typecast it to an object.

EDIT:
In MainActivity, it requires importing the right class.
Sample code:

```
import package.Current_forecast_fragment;
```

Note: You need to reference the fragment class by specifying the correct path.

Again, this should not be too difficult. Have fun, good luck, don't give up!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did try this but I am getting the same null pointer exeption :/

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev, I added new comments in my post (under EDIT) since you added more code to MainActivity. In this case though, I did not see the imports.